# To Get get all user tables row count when performing insert transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

[image]

Basically What I am doing is I get all tables row count before Inserting new data(final commit) in one full transaction scope, In my case, its working single transaction and but it is not working when performing multiple transactions at the same time.

The 2nd transaction query operation moving to wait (get all rows count ) at the same time my 1st transaction perform an insert operation

Also, I have tried as IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted and it is not working

Comment: This doesn't clear for understanding. What is your problem? Does may form a question?

Comment: I need to get all tables row count while insert transaction is still running. Get count query operation still processing ( 2nd Transaction ) while my 1st  transaction insert operation not completd

Comment: @meowmeow have you understand now?

Comment: @RavisankarMani no, you need to provide enough information for us to reproduce the issue.   Start here:   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TabAlleman : Please find the image link in the description for more information  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfl20.png

Comment: @RavisankarMani If the transaction isn't committed it means that it inserts nothing because MSS is a relational database. I don't sure that reducing of isolation level is able to resolve your issue. So I think that particular insert (for instance,  insert 1000 rows -> commit -> insert 1000 rows -> <repeat it>) is the best solution for this case. Also, you can describe a goal why you want to make inserts in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are attempting to get is a running progress of the insertions as they are committed. Is this correct?

If so, the problem is SQL Server commits in batches and therefore you are not able to access it until the commit is complete. One approach to this is to break out your insertion transactions into smaller batches then you can query them. Bear in mind this is untested psuedo code however I have done something similar in the past using a WHILE LOOP.

First collect your initial batch of records to commit:

```
SELECT * FROM table // get your 100,000 records
INTO #holdingTable
```

Then create a while loop based on chunks of say 1,000

```
DECLARE @totalCount int = 100000, @myCount int = 1000

WHILE (@myCount <= @totalCount)
BEGIN
   SELECT top 1000 Id from #holdingTable
   INTO #tempHolding

   INSERT #tempHolding INTO myTable

   DELETE #tempHolding FROM #holdingTable

   SET @myCount = @myCount + 1000
END
```

The idea is to loop the 100,000 records in chunks of 1,000, insert them and then remove the inserted ones from the temp table so that you can select the next 1,000. Similar to paging. The key is to remove them as you go so you don't insert the same records more than once.

It's not a finished solution but I hope this helps steer you in the right direction.